# How to get the GraphQl errors in react component or a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

I am using @apollo/client and everything is working fine. In my index.ts I am logging the Graphql errors

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
if (graphQLErrors) {
graphQLErrors.map(({ message, extensions }) => {
console.log(`[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${extensions.code}`);
     });
   }

if (networkError) {
handle network error
console.log(networkError);
   }
 });
```

and I am able to see the exact errors thrown by the grapql query. But I am not able to get these errors in my components.

I am having a custom hook to call the queries and for errors I have implemented the below code

```
const { loading: letLoading, error: letError, data: letData } = useQuery(fetchTypes, {
    variables: { input: { country: 'deu' }, errorPolicy: "all" },
  });


function fetchLETService() {
    setLetStatus({ letLoading });
    if (letError) {
      console.log(letError)
    }
    if (letData) {
      setLetStatus({ letLoading: false, letData: letData.types });
    }
  }
```

But all I get here is

> Response not successful: Received status code 400

I am expecting the below error, which I am getting in index.ts

> [GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$input" got invalid value { country: "deu" }; Field "accountProduct" of required type "String!" was not provided., Location: BAD_USER_INPUT

Answer (score -1):

try using onError function. Hope this helps

```
const { loading: letLoading, error: letError, data: letData } = useQuery(fetchTypes, {
    variables: { input: { country: 'deu' }, errorPolicy: "all" },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log(error)
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks but this also gives the same server error Response not successful: Received status code 400. But I want graphql errors.